# MySQL Int Range select

Tags: mysql

[image: Screenshot of table]

I have a table, with `attribute range` (`range_type` is min (-1) and max (1) values of attribute) and `attribute_value` is value. I need to select a range for example from -1 to 15.

I need receive product 2 only because his min value is -5 less than -1 and max value is 18 more than 15.

I try something like this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM `attribute_range`
WHERE
(`range_type` = -1 AND `attribute_value` <= -1)
AND
(`range_type` = 1 AND `attribute_value` >= 15)
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: Check the type column has to be numeric, not varchar. Remove the quotes from numbers.

Comment: The condition of your query reads `range_type = -1 AND range_type = 1`. How could `range_type` be `-1` and `1` on the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a subquery:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM `attribute_range`
WHERE (`range_type` = -1 AND `attribute_value` <= -1)
      AND produc_id in 
           (SELECT product_id
            FROM `attribute_range`
            WHERE (`range_type` = 1 AND `attribute_value` >= 15))
```

Comment: In this case I receive product id 1 and 2, I need 2 only, because product 1 max value is 12 less than 15

Comment: Ok, i undestand now, i change my answer